# SharePoint web front end servers updated before app servers, now app servers won't update

Tags: sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

I made a careless mistake when running cumulative updates on a SharePoint farm and updated the web front end servers first before running on the app servers. Now the update files wont run on the app server. My WFE servers are updated service pack 2 and my app servers don't even have service pack 1 installed. When I try to run the update files on the app server it fails with "An error occurred while running detection."

Is there anything I can do at this point to force the update on the app server?

Comment: Just to clarify: Did you apply the cu's on the web front ends and then ran the wizard and now you can't apply the cu to the application servers?

Comment: could you please give more information....what is sequence of the installtion of the CU....from which version you are going which version? when you apply cu on the WFE servers did you run the config wizard?

Comment: Waqas, I have not run the config wizard on the wfe servers. I took a screen shot of the manage patch status page in CA: http://i.imgur.com/WIinwaS.png
Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

That might not be the real problem. There may be a mix-up in the versioning which you can solve by running a PowerShell Script. This script will force a timer job to start and fix things for you. Run the Script:

```
Get-SPProduct –Local
```

On the server you want to update. Wait. Wait a little longer until it is finished. When done you can try to update the server in question and don’t forget to run PSConfig once you’re done with the update. I assume you have run PSConfig on the WFE: s as well.

If that doesn’t work you may have to disconnect the WFE servers from Central Admin and try again.